# CodeIgniter conditional logic (if..else) for handling different inputs of same variable in query builder

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select(); 
$this->db->from('demo');
$this->db->where('city',html_escape($this->input->post('input',TRUE))); 
$this->db->where('name',$a);
// if $a = "none" then no where clause with $a
// if $a != "none" then apply where clause with $a

$this->db->where('car',$b);
// what was tried -> if..else 
// e.g if ($a == "none") {
// } else {
// $this->db->where('name',$a);
// }
// if condition works till above line, but then it fails to generate proper query string
// in below $c variable
// e.g if ($c == "none") {
// } else {
// $this->db->where('bike',$c);
// }

$this->db->where('bike',$c);
// if $c = "none" then no where clause with $c
// if $c != "none" then apply where clause with $c
$this->db->where('status', $d);
$this->db->order_by('price','desc');
$this->db->limit(25,0);
// echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
```

Is there any simple way do this in linear fashion, including above conditional logic, or one has to build query string manually.

Edit 1: If I remove if..else conditions query runs as expected.

Comment: in your commented code you say `if $a = "none" then no where clause with $a`. Do you expect that to come "with" the query or is it already established before the query?

Comment: Just place the query line inside the conditional statements

Comment: @Vickel $a is established before the query, so while building query, we have information what value $a has. ($a is coming via POST method input)

Comment: @ParkerDell yes, your suggestion, was tried, but it fails, at second if condition at $c, for reason unknown to me. get_compiled_select(); method showed, that query was not formed properly.

Comment: You don’t need empty select leave it off and it queries as select *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is, you can add conditional logic at anywhere in the query builder:

```
if($a){
  $this->db->where('name',$a);
}
```

or

```
if (isset($a)){
  $this->db->where('name',$a);
}
```

or

```
if (!$a==null){
  $this->db->where('name',$a);
}
```

or combination of above...